# Show the total value of increase and decrease amount

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jQuery. I am trying to increase and decrease value on `click` on the button.
Now I want to show  the sum of three input on total `input`.

Here is what I tried :

```js
var cartButtons = $('.cart-plus-minus').find('button');
$(cartButtons).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var target = $this.parent().data('target');
  var target = $('#' + target);
  var current = parseFloat($(target).val());
  if ($this.hasClass('cart-plus-1'))
    target.val(current + 1);
  else {
    (current < 2) ? null: target.val(current - 1);
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cart-plus-minus {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Increment / Decrement an 'amount' input.</h1>

<a href="" class="a-link">
  <label> Total amount is: </label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="" value="0">
</a>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-1">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-1" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>

<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-2">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-2" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-2">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-2" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you mean by total amount? is it sum of three inputs?

Comment: you want the total increase and desrease value  show on total value?

Comment: "Now I want to put the total amount inside an input. Here's what I tried". There's no attempt here to do what you're saying you want. All you've done is created the textbox. not much of a "try". You've shown you already know how to put values in a textbox, and read values from a textbox. It's basically the same, except you have to fetch from all 3 textboxes and do some basic maths.

Comment: yes. @yajiv . the sum of three input show on total.

Comment: You are already putting each total in an input, so the code will be very similar - I can't imagine this being too difficult if you already did the first part.

Comment: your 3rd div has a copy paste error by having `amount-2` again need to change it to `amount-3` and the input's id inside to `amount-3`

Comment: P.S. Your +/- buttons allow the user to set values beyond your min and max values specified in the input's attributes, so that needs sorting out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to iterate on the inputs and add the value of these to a variable. 
 And then set it as an input value to the total input field.

```
  var total = 0;

  $('.cart-plus-minus input').each(function(){
    total += +this.value;
  });

  $("#total").val(total);
```

```js
var cartButtons = $('.cart-plus-minus').find('button');

$(cartButtons).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var target = $this.parent().data('target');
  var target = $('#' + target);
  var current = parseFloat($(target).val());
  if ($this.hasClass('cart-plus-1'))
    target.val(current + 1);
  else {
    (current < 2) ? null: target.val(current - 1);
  }
  
  var total = 0;
  $('.cart-plus-minus input').each(function(){
    total += +this.value;
  });
  
  $("#total").val(total);
  
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cart-plus-minus {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Increment / Decrement an 'amount' input.</h1>

<a href="" class="a-link">
  <label> Total amount is: </label>
  <input id="total" type="text" placeholder="" value="3">
</a>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-1">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-1" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>

<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-2">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-2" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-3">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-3" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

See below for a working example. Basically, you just need to assign an `id` to the total input box (not necessary, but easier) then in your event listener, tally up the total of all three boxes and put the result into the first input box.

*One thing to note:*

- Your third increment box had the same `id` and `data-target` values as the second one, resulting in the buttons for the third box affecting the value in the second box (fixed in the solution below).

```js
var cartButtons = $('.cart-plus-minus').find('button');
$(cartButtons).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var target = $this.parent().data('target');
  var target = $('#' + target);
  var current = parseFloat($(target).val());
  if ($this.hasClass('cart-plus-1'))
    target.val(current + 1);
  else {
    (current < 2) ? null: target.val(current - 1);
  }
  getTotal();
});

function getTotal() {
  document.getElementById('total').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('amount-1').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('amount-2').value) + parseInt(document.getElementById('amount-3').value);
}

getTotal();
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cart-plus-minus {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Increment / Decrement an 'amount' input.</h1>

<a href="" class="a-link">
  <label> Total amount is: </label>
  <input id="total" type="text" placeholder="" value="0">
</a>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-1">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-1" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>

<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-2">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-2" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-3">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-3" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `val()` jQuery to get the `input` value and then add them by converting to `int` using `parseInt`

***Stack Snippet***

```js
var cartButtons = $('.cart-plus-minus').find('button');
var total = parseInt($("#amount-1").val()) + parseInt($("#amount-2").val()) + parseInt($("#amount-3").val());
$("#total").val(total);
$(cartButtons).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var target = $this.parent().data('target');
  var target = $('#' + target);
  var current = parseFloat($(target).val());
  if ($this.hasClass('cart-plus-1'))
    target.val(current + 1);
  else {
    (current < 2) ? null: target.val(current - 1);
  }
  total = parseInt($("#amount-1").val()) + parseInt($("#amount-2").val()) + parseInt($("#amount-3").val());
  $("#total").val(total);
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cart-plus-minus {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Increment / Decrement an 'amount' input.</h1>

<a href="" class="a-link">
  <label> Total amount is: </label>
  <input type="text" placeholder="" value="0" id="total">
</a>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-1">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-1" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>

<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-2">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-2" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-3">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-3" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```js
var cartButtons = $('.cart-plus-minus').find('button');
$(cartButtons).on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var $this = $(this);
  var target = $this.parent().data('target');
  var target = $('#' + target);
  var current = parseFloat($(target).val());
  var total=parseFloat($('#total').val())
  if ($this.hasClass('cart-plus-1')){
    target.val(current + 1);
    $('#total').val(total+1);
  }
  else {
    if(current >= 2){
     target.val(current - 1);
     $('#total').val(total-1);
     }
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.cart-plus-minus {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<h1>Increment / Decrement an 'amount' input.</h1>

<a href="" class="a-link">
  <label> Total amount is: </label>
  <input type="text" id="total" placeholder="" value="3">
</a>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-1">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-1" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>

<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-2">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-2" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
<div class="cart-plus-minus" data-target="amount-3">
  <button class="btn cart-minus-1">-</button>
  <input type="number" id="amount-3" value="1" min="1" max="300">
  <button class="btn cart-plus-1">+</button>
</div>
```